# Ceiling height required for standing upright a piece of furtniture

Tags: geometry

Say you have a piece of furniture with height $h$ and depth $d$ that you want to stand upright from the floor, what is the ceiling height required $H$?

[image]

(Apoligies if the graphic isn't correct, the movement of the points would seem to follow a circle to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the front view of the furniture lying flat on the floor in initial condition, it looks like a rectangular section & the rotation is made about the lower-left edge point then in this case, the diagonal of the rectangular section will follow a circular path having maximum possible radius which is equal to the diagonal of the rectangular section.

Hence ceiling height has to be equal to the diagonal of rectangle to allow the free rotation of the furniture to stand upright.

Thus, the maximum length, of the furniture that will rotate, about the edge point is  $$=\text{diagonal of the rectangle with sides} \ d\  \& \ h$$$$=\sqrt{h^2+d^2}$$   The ceiling height required to stand the furniture upright is equal to the diagonal of rectangle hence
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{Ceiling height:} \ \color{blue}{H=\sqrt{h^2+d^2}}}}$$